# NextJS Client Side Code Rendering Failure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm so perplexed by this...

Everything generates as expected except for onClick code and useEffect code. I tried running `document.querySelector('button');` on the console, to retrieve undefined. It seems that JS is not seeing anything on the dom. This is only affecting one Page.tsx file that uses components.

### Key Problem:

When the button is pressed, no code runs.

### Attempted Solutions:

I tried making all new files, making the button super simple where all it does is log one line, deleting all the code I wrote and logging a simple line to a client-side console. I have no idea what is wrong with this.

### My code:

@/app/article/create/page.tsx:

```
import Nav from '@/components/$page/Nav'
import Footer from '@/components/$page/Footer'
import ArticleBox from '@/components/cards/ArticleBox'
import { dbCloseConnection, dbGetConnection, dbInsertArticle, dbUpdateArticle } from '@/lib/database/dbQueries'
import { Article } from '@/lib/interface/dbArticle'
import BtnCreateArticle from '@/components/elements/create_article/BtnCreateArticle'

export default function Create() {
  
  async function CreateNewArticle() {
    "use server";
    await dbGetConnection();

    /// Insert a new article
    const articleRtn = await dbInsertArticle('article' + Math.random().toString(), 1)
    if (articleRtn.status === 1 && articleRtn.data != null) {
      let article: Article = articleRtn.data;

      /// Update article Title
      const tmpArticle = (await dbUpdateArticle(article.id, "article" + article.id));
      if (tmpArticle.status === 1 && tmpArticle.data != null) article = tmpArticle.data;
      dbCloseConnection();
      return `/article/create/${article.id}`;
    }
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    await dbCloseConnection();
    return "/"
  }
  
  return (
    <main className='pgeArticle'>
      <Nav/>
      <div className="content-wrapper col-reverse">
        <div className="articles-list">
          <h1>Create New Article</h1>
          <div className="create-content-hldr">
            <BtnCreateArticle Clicked={CreateNewArticle} />
          </div>

        </div>
        <div className="articles-list side">
          <h2>Edit Previous Articles:</h2>
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/muscleman.JPG' title="The Power of Strength Training" desc="Discover the benefits of strength training and how it can increase bone density, boost metabolism, and improve performance."/>
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/nutritionchick.jpg' title="Nutrition Tips for Optimal Performance" desc="Dive into the world of nutrition and learn how to fuel your body for peak performance." />
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/meditation.jpg' title="Mental Well-being and Fitness" desc="Explore the profound connection between mind and body as we delve into the world of mindfulness and fitness." />
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/muscleman.JPG' title="The Power of Strength Training" desc="Discover the benefits of strength training and how it can increase bone density, boost metabolism, and improve performance."/>
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/muscleman.JPG' title="The Power of Strength Training" desc="Discover the benefits of strength training and how it can increase bone density, boost metabolism, and improve performance."/>
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/nutritionchick.jpg' title="Nutrition Tips for Optimal Performance" desc="Dive into the world of nutrition and learn how to fuel your body for peak performance." />
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/meditation.jpg' title="Mental Well-being and Fitness" desc="Explore the profound connection between mind and body as we delve into the world of mindfulness and fitness." />
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/muscleman.JPG' title="The Power of Strength Training" desc="Discover the benefits of strength training and how it can increase bone density, boost metabolism, and improve performance."/>
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/muscleman.JPG' title="The Power of Strength Training" desc="Discover the benefits of strength training and how it can increase bone density, boost metabolism, and improve performance."/>
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/nutritionchick.jpg' title="Nutrition Tips for Optimal Performance" desc="Dive into the world of nutrition and learn how to fuel your body for peak performance." />
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/meditation.jpg' title="Mental Well-being and Fitness" desc="Explore the profound connection between mind and body as we delve into the world of mindfulness and fitness." />
          <ArticleBox ver='hor' imgPath='/images/muscleman.JPG' title="The Power of Strength Training" desc="Discover the benefits of strength training and how it can increase bone density, boost metabolism, and improve performance."/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </main>
  )
}
```

@/components/elements/create_article/BtnCreateArticle.tsx:

```
'use client'
import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

type props = {
  className?: string;
  Clicked: () => Promise<string>;
}

const BtnCreateArticle : React.FC<props> = ({className = '', Clicked}) => {
  const linkButtonRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  const [articleCreated, setArticleCreated] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [link, setLink] = useState('/');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("TESTTTT")
        // Find the element with the class 'BtnCreateArticle'
    const buttonElement = document.querySelector('.BtnCreateArticle');
    console.log("btn: " + buttonElement);
    // Check if the element exists before adding the onclick event
    if (buttonElement) {
      
      buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('Clicked');
      });
    }
  }, [])
  
  const handleClick = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      // Call the onClick function and await its result (the URL)
      const url = await Clicked();
      // Use the redirect function to navigate to the new page
      
      setLink(url);
      console.log(link)
      setArticleCreated(true);
      linkButtonRef.current ? linkButtonRef.current.click() : null;
      //redirect(url);
      
      //  const router = useRouter()
      //  router.push(url)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while creating new article:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}>click</button>
      {articleCreated ? 
      <Link href={link}><button ref={linkButtonRef} className={`BtnCreateArticle ${className}`}>Edit New Article</button></Link>
      : <button className={`BtnCreateArticle ${className}`} onClick={async () => {isLoading ? null : handleClick()}} disabled={isLoading}>{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Create New'}</button>

      } 
    </>
  )
}

export default BtnCreateArticle;
```

Does anyone know what could possibly be causing this? Maybe it's something in my NextJS project settings?

Answer (score 0):

useEffect runs before the DOM is rendered, therefore you won't see the button yet. As a general rule, don't use vanilla event listeners with React if you are just starting. use the `onClick` prop for the button instead.

Comment: I'm using vanilla because the onClick failed.

Comment: What do you mean by onClick failing? You have 3 buttons on that component, which one "failed"?

Comment: All of them. I fixed it somehow. I added "use server" to the top of the page.tsx, saved, then removed. That seemed to make it magically work...

Comment: I added the extra buttons for troubleshooting. I guess it's just a framework glitch.

Comment: Ah, got it. Yeah, probably it got "stuck" thinking that you were in a server component. Glad that you figured it out.